# python linked list time limit exceed

Tags: python, list, linked-list

I was doing some programming problems today on leetcode.
The problem I was trying to solve is over on this [link](https://leetcode.com/problems/odd-even-linked-list/).

I was able to solve the problem using the code below:

```
class Solution(object):
    def oddEvenList(self, head):
        if not head:
            return head

        oddPointer = head
        evenPointer = head.next
        temp = head.next
        while evenPointer and evenPointer.next:
            oddPointer.next = evenPointer.next
            oddPointer = oddPointer.next
            evenPointer.next = oddPointer.next
            evenPointer = evenPointer.next

        oddPointer.next = temp
        return head
```

However if I change to the code below, the online judges give me a time limit exceed error. I was wondering what the problem is over here.

```
class Solution(object):
    def oddEvenList(self, head):
        if not head:
            return head

        oddPointer = head
        evenPointer = head.next
        while evenPointer and evenPointer.next:
            oddPointer.next = evenPointer.next
            oddPointer = oddPointer.next
            evenPointer.next = oddPointer.next
            evenPointer = evenPointer.next

        oddPointer.next = head.next #this is the change
        return head
```

I remembered I could do this in Java, but for some reason python can't do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some testing and found out that there was a infinity loop inside the code that was causing the time limit exceed error. In my code: `oddPointer.next = head.next` this line will always point back to itself.

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, you have these three lines (I've removed all lines not relevant to the answer):

```
oddPointer = head
oddPointer.next = evenPointer.next
oddPointer = head.next
```

When the 2nd line is executed, `oddPointer` and `head` both refer to the same object. The line overwrites `<that object>.next`, i.e. it overwrites `head.next`.  The original value of `head.next` is now irretrievably lost.

In your first example, you've stashed away the original value of `head.next` in the `temp` variable, so you can retrieve it later.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! I have a follow up question: in this case wouldn't there still be a value for head.next?